# How can I recover local repo files if Github Desktop and Rstudio have interacted to corrupt the repo?

Tags: git, github, version-control, rstudio

My question is in the title; here are the details to help a git expert answer my question. It appears two branches of my local repo have become "mixed up": some files have appeared on a branch they were never on; many files have disappeared completely. My *theory* is that simultaneous use of two git-connected applications (Github Desktop and Rstudio) caused the problem - explained below.

I have a git project with several branches, let's focus on `branch1` and `branch2`. In `branch2/Applications` I had thousands of files. `branch1` had no such Applications folder. This was the normal situation.

To prep for a **long**-overdue commit and sync to remote, I was cleaning up this project locally, mostly on `branch2` (by modifying `.gitignore` and also moving some files to non-git local folders). At the same time I was using Github Desktop to switch back and forth between `branch1` and `branch2`, a few times going as fast as once every 30 seconds. An Rstudio project (`.Rproj`) that lives in my repo's local directory was also open. *Note, this `.Rproj` did not exist on `branch1`, yet the file remained open while I used Github to switch back and forth between `branch1` and `branch2` repeatedly.*

Mysteriously, the large folder (15000+ files) `Applications` on `branch2` disappeared from the filesystem. I closed Github and Rstudio, and the git process ran in the background at high CPU load for several hours. I killed the process.

The current puzzling situation is:

- `branch2/Applications` is completely missing. Why? I did add it to `.gitignore`, but my understanding is it should still appear on my local filesystem.
- Though it shouldn't, `branch1/Applications` now exists. But it only contains a small portion of the 15000+ files which ought to be on `branch2/Applications`. Why?
- The `.Rproj` file has also "jumped branches." It now appears in the file system when `branch1` is selected in Github, although before today's problems it was a `branch2` file.

My theory is that I switched too fast (or something) between branches in Github, which did not allow Rstudio's git monitoring to "catch up", and somehow the local repo got corrupted.

Is it possible for Github and Rstudio to interact to corrupt a local repo? And if so, do you have guidance for how I should proceed to attempt to recover the large folder? I'm not a git expert but can research commands if anyone has ideas. I don't know where to start.

FYI the large folder does not appear in a recent form on the remote repo, since it had been so long since my last push. So I don't think I can recover it from there.

Comment: What does `git status` show on each of the two branches now?

Comment: @JohnZwinck on branch1 (master), it's up-to-date with 'origin/master'. It lists several untracked files, including the large folder (which again, should not even be there). "Nothing added to commit but untracked files present." 
On branch2: up-to-date with 'origin/branch2' and "nothing to commit, working directory clean"

Comment: What's the name of the "large folder"?  Had you committed it on either branch?  If so, are you able to find the commit in the "git log" on either branch?

Comment: The large folder is `~/github/Applications`. It is not in the commit history of `master` (branch1). It was never pushed on `branch2` - the folder always sat as a local, tracked folder which I unchecked (which I believe means to unstage them?) in Github Desktop at every commit. 

I do have a commit from today where, on `branch2`, I modified `.gitignore`. That addition to `.gitignore` is 

`Applications/*      # ignore everything in the directory.`

Comment: You say the folder was "tracked" which means it was committed.  But you also say you deselected it every time in GitHub Desktop, which implies you did not commit it.  Was it committed?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Sorry for my confusion in the terminology due to beginner status with git. No -- I do not see that the folder or its files were ever committed. I used the word "tracked" (maybe incorrectly) to reflect that Github Desktop / git would notice changes to the files within `Applications` -- if I modified a file within, Github Desktop would display that change and allow me to commit if I wanted.

Comment: Just a suggestion for future questions:  if you're a beginner with git, it's more likely that you did something wrong than that the tools corrupted your repo.  Suggesting that tools people spent a long time developing and gave to you for free are at fault will irritate the developers, and you might not get as much help as you would otherwise.

Comment: @user2554330 I see what you mean in hindsight. Thanks. It's just that I'm not fluent enough in `git` to properly describe what I'm even seeing. I believe that describing what *appears* (to a novice) to have happened may give some details to an expert that can be used to answer the question... if that makes sense. As a newbie to Stack Overflow as well, I've found it's comically impossible to never irritate anyone, even with questions which are in fact (if not in appearance) humble. I'd rather be precise & wrong than to post a meek/vague question making no guesses whatsoever. LOVE RStudio btw

Comment: @NiceStats Since you haven’t committed `Applications` into git repo, what’s the changes did you commit in your local repo? And did you sync your local repo with remote repo before the local repo corrupted? And what’s the `git reflog` shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing to restore the files. (Note that I do not actually want these private results files in a public git repo after all, so all I need to do is write them out to disk somewhere.) I ran `git log --raw --all` and found what looked to be the full list of missing files where each line had the original full file path, as well as a SHA. Fantastic. Then I wrote a script with each line containing something like

```
git cat-file -p [SHA] > "/full/path/file.ext"
```

This restored file types to their original condition and subdirectory structure, including text-based files as well as `pdf`, `tar.gz`, and `R` objects which had been saved from the `R` workspace.

Thanks for everyone's help. In the end, probably the key step in causing this error was that I interrupted the git process in the middle of Github Desktop doing a stash operation on the 15000+ files while I was switching branches. I assume that caused the git branches to get crossed up.